# Powershell trying to backup from 2 locations using if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple program in Powershell. What I'm trying to do is backup two different folders into one location, if the user chooses 'Y' by the prompt. If the user chooses 'N' then the user shouldn't be prompted for a second folder and should instead just be prompted for the backup location.

However, it's not working for me and I'm stuck. Is anyone able to help? Much appreciated.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
#If there is a error stop!
$theFolder = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter folder location you wish to backup"
# variable 'theFolder' = the entered file location.
$question = Read-Host -Prompt "Would you like to backup another folder? 'Y' or 'N'"
if ($question -eq 'Y') {$moreFolder = Read-Host "Enter second folder location"} else
# variable 'backup' = the entered backup location
{$backup = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter backup location"}
echo $thefolder
echo $backup
echo $moreFolder
# checking to see if there is a connection there.
Test-Path $theFolder
Test-Path $moreFolder
Test-Path $backup
# testing the path of both the folder and backup location
Copy-Item -Path $theFolder\* -Destination $backup -Recurse
Copy-Item -path $moreFolder\* -Destination $backup -Recurse
# copy via file pathway defined ealier. put into destination staging.
# recurse = bypass all prompts (are you sure etc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the smallest pieces of code it is helpful to structure your code by indenting. Just by doing that I discovered the error: when the user of the script chooses to enter a second folder to backup the script will not ask for the backup location. Here:

```
if ($question -eq 'Y') {
  $moreFolder = Read-Host "Enter second folder location"
} 
else {
  # variable 'backup' = the entered backup location
  $backup = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter backup location"
}
```

So you should remove the else clause there and have something like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
#If there is a error stop!
$theFolder = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter folder location you wish to backup"
# variable 'theFolder' = the entered file location.
$question = Read-Host -Prompt "Would you like to backup another folder? 'Y' or 'N'"

if ($question -eq 'Y') {
    $moreFolder = Read-Host "Enter second folder location"
} 

# variable 'backup' = the entered backup location
$backup = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter backup location"

# testing the path of both the folder and backup location
if ((Test-Path $theFolder) -and (Test-Path $backup)) {
    Copy-Item -Path $theFolder\* -Destination $backup -Recurse
    if (Test-Path $moreFolder) {
        Copy-Item -path $moreFolder\* -Destination $backup -Recurse
    }
}
```

One more remark: the -Recurse parameter for Copy-Item is about recursing through the folder structure, not to prevent questions like 'are you sure'. For that purpose is -Confirm:$false

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to not only write out a working script based upon my own, but to also explain in such detail. This is very much appreciated. Thanks again.